# Integration of divergence of product of current density and $x$-component of position in wave mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction

I want to know what is "integration of divergence of product of current density and $x$-component of position in wave mechanics":

i.e.

$$\int \boldsymbol \nabla \cdot (\boldsymbol j x) ~ d\tau $$

where current density is given by:

$$ \boldsymbol j = (\hbar/2\mu i) (\psi ^* \boldsymbol \nabla \psi - (\boldsymbol \nabla \psi^*)\psi)$$

Please elaborate steps of actual integration. Book only says that this integral is zero under the assumption that $ \psi $ vanishes sufficiently fast at infinity.

Comment: Why are you integrating in time?

Comment: @CosmasZachos : It is volume integration; in Cartesian co-ordinate system, it is $d \tau = dx*dy*dz$

Comment: So what does Gauss’s law say for everything attenuating at infinity?